# Arch Linux / Virtualenv: Python 3.5 failed after system upgrade

Tags: arch-linux, python, virtualenv

I updated my arch linux system just now. It upgraded my Python 3.5 to 3.6. When using python in the main environment, it works fine:

```
[yuanyin@YuanYin ~]$ python
Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan 16 2017, 12:12:55)
[GCC 6.3.1 20170109] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But when I workon some virtual environment, it reported an error:

```
[yuanyin@YuanYin ~]$ workon transcats
(transcats) [yuanyin@YuanYin ~]$ python
python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Isn't a virtual environment supposed to work as an isolated environment?

Should I reinstall Python in the `virtualenv`?

Comment: I guess when Python was updated on your host it removed libs for the previous version. The easiest thing you can do is to just reinit `virtualenv` with a newly installed python version.

Comment: @ddnomad Thx. I just removed the virtualenv and create a new one with the same name. Then after pip installing the requirement.txt packages, python came back to life.